# server side validation of dynamics inputs - laracast

Tags: laravel

I've a form where user can update name and rate. Here user can dynamically add the inputs as well so that they can send multiple items at once. But I wonder how to validate them.

controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //how to validate name and rate so that they are not empty & name should be unique here? 
    if ($request->get('name')) {
        foreach ($request->get('name') as $key => $value) {
            ItemType::create([
                'name' => $request->get('name')[$key],
                'rate' => $request->get('rate')[$key],
            ]);
        }
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Generally the validation is done as below but how to implement in above scenario for dynamic inputs?

```
$request->validate([
   'name' => 'required|unique:name',
   'rate' => 'required',
]);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You can use array as names for the inputs and use array validation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-arrays

Comment: did you try somting like 'name.*' => 'required'